# How to repair warning: missing braces around initializer?

Tags: gcc, vala

The warning is produced by the c code generated by vala.

> warning: missing braces around initializer

The code works but the warning is annoying. The vala code referenced by the warning is

```
struct Position {uint x; uint y;}
private static Position positions[8];
```

The generated C code is

```
static Position det_positions[8] = {0};
```

I've tried initializing positions half a dozen different ways but can't seem to get the syntax  to satisfy the warning. Is this [GCC bug 53119](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11552408/398460) or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I don't get this warning with Vala 0.16 or 0.18 on GCC 4.6.3. Care to share your environment? Also, what is the generated C that is causing the problem?

Comment: @apmasell The embedded linux target is a Leopardboard 368, the GCC is 4.4.1, the toolchain is codesourcery/arm-2010q1, and I've added the generated C to the question. I've also properly formatted the code which I forgot to do earlier.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be related to [GCC bug 53119](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53119). It goes away if you change the C declaration to `{{0}}`. Your options are:

1. Ignore the warning.
2. Manipulate the C code after generation to have `{{0}}` instead of `{0}` on that line using `sed` or the like.
3. Declare the array `extern` in Vala, and write the C definition elsewhere. (The permanent version of #2.)
4. Do something like `struct foo { int bar; Position positions[8]; } static foo position_holder` and `{0}` will then be initialising `position_holder.bar` which is fine and the warning goes away.

Comment: Or add "-Wno-missing-braces" to your compile to silence the invalid warning.

Comment: Note, however, that the warning is not invalid in general! Just for the zero initialization (i.e. ``= {0}``), it is always invalid. See [Adit Ya's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21873585/490560) for a valid case for the warning.

Answer (score 20):

This warning also appears when a multi-dimensional array is treated as a linear array ( although it is still correct and the code runs perfectly ) with -Wall compiler flags set.

For example

```
char array[5][10][2] = {\
"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",\
"1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",\
"2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2",\
"3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3",\
"4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4" };
```

This will generate the warning.

Do the following changes to remove the warnings as shown below

```
char array[5][10][2] = {\
{"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0" },\
{"1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"},\
{"2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"},\
{"3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3"},\
{"4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4"} };
```

Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In this example the first and second level of the array are entered with `{`, and the third by defining strings (ending in `'\0'`) entered with `"`. In 2D, if you also use the strings, then use only one level of `{`: `{"0"}` i.e. `char '0'` then `char '\0'` followed by zeros and if you don't use strings then two levels of `{`: `{{0}}` i.e. zeros only.