# How to initialize array in an array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, struct, initialization

Let's assume I have a structure defined as:

```
typedef struct _TStruct {

    uint Values[3];

} TStruct;
```

Then I define an array of structures:

```
TStruct Data[3];
```

How do I correctly initialize the arrays in this array of structures?

Comment: The cited dup and [GCC 53119 bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53119) seems to surface when using `{0}` with missing braces. This question does not appear to be initializing that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly initialize an array in an array of structures you need to do the following:

```
typedef struct _TStruct {

    uint Values[3];

} TStruct;

TStruct Data[3] = {

    {{ 0x86, 0x55, 0x79 }}, {{ 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc }}, {{ 0x76, 0x23, 0x24 }}

};
```

Pay attention to the double braces around every group of values. The additional pair of braces is essential to avoid getting a following gcc error (only when `-Wall` flag is present, precisely it's "detected" by `gcc` `-Wmissing-braces` flag):

> warning: missing braces around initializer

**Note**:

1. Usage of double braces `{{ }}` does not change the layout of data in memory
2. This warning does not appear on MS Visual Studio C++ compiler

**See also:**

[How to repair warning: missing braces around initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746033/how-to-repair-warning-missing-braces-around-initializer)

[GCC Bug 53319](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53119)

Comment: Your Q & A is a duplicate of the linked Q & A you provided. Why posting that then?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There was no question/answer on SO showing how to initialize array in an array of structs

Comment: Note that omitting braces is also correct according to the C Standard. The extra bracing is only "required" to work around a compiler defect.