# How to copy string from a single dimensional array to 2d array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to copy same characters from an single dimensional char array to each row of a 2d array,but I cant any output.

Expected output:

```
            abcd  
            abcd  
            abcd  
            abcd
```

Output I got:

```
process returned -1073741819(0xC0000005) execution time : 4.583s  
press any key to continue
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int i,j;
    char v[4]={'a','b','c','d'};
    char answers[10][10];
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            strcpy(answers[i][j],v[i]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("\n%s",answers[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `<conio.h>`? Which era you're in?

Comment: my university is still in 1995,:D

Comment: What did your debugger tell you?

Comment: You need to study how strings and 1D arrays work before worrying about 2D arrays. Also pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: my compiler just gives me warning "missing braces aroung initializer ",even though  the braces are correctly placed.I found out that it is just a bug in gcc.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746033/how-to-repair-warning-missing-braces-around-initializer).I am using code blocks ide 16.01 and gcc 8.2.0,do i need to update anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

```
strcpy(answers[i][j],v[i]);
```

but, neither `answers[i][j]` nor `v[i]` is a *string* (or, pointer to a `char` array). You're essentially accessing out of bound memory, thereby invoking undefined behaviour.

**Solution:** You can simply use the assignment operator `=`, to copy each element one by one.

That said, if you want to use the `answers[i]` as *string*, (as seen in `printf("\n%s",answers[i]);`) you need to make sure it's null-terminated. A quick way of achieving that would be to initialize the array to `0` upon definition.

Something like

```
 char answers[10][10] = {0};  // ensure the elements are zero-initialized
```

Comment: can u provide a solution as to get the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

Strings in C are null-terminated. Try this instead:

```
char v[5] = { 'a','b','c','d', '\0' };
```

Also this here

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        strcpy(answers[i][j],v[i]);
    }
}
```

Doesn't work because you're trying to copy characters, but this function expects strings. Your compiler should issue a warning about incompatible types. Replace this nested loop with this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    strcpy(answers[i], v);
}
```