# Are curly braces really required around initialization?

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

According to GCC 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) I'm missing a curly brace in the array initialization in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <array>

int main(){
  int                   plain[]   = {1,2,3,4,5};
  std::array  <int, 5>  std_arr   = {1,2,3,4,5}; // warning, see below
  boost::array<int, 5>  boost_arr = {1,2,3,4,5}; // warning, see below
  std::cout << plain[0] << std_arr[1] << boost_arr[2] << std::endl;
}
```

```
> g++ test.cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic --std=c++0x                                                                                  
test.cc: in function »int main()«:
test.cc:7:47: warning: curly braces missing around initialization for »std::array::value_type [5] {aka int [5]}« [-Wmissing-braces]
test.cc:8:47: warning: curly braces missing around initialization for »int [5]« [-Wmissing-braces]
```

Apparently ([GCC missing braces around initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551986/gcc-missing-braces-around-initializer)) this is a bug in GCC, even in a slightly different context. The answers differ from "file a bug report" to "just disable the warning".

However, in the context of `std::array` or `boost::array`, is this warning superfluous, or am I missing something important?

(I will probably add the additional braces instead of disabling the warning, but I'm curious about the implications)

Comment: It's a warning. If it was "required", it would be an error.

Comment: shouldn't it be `std::array<int,5} arr{1,2,3,4,5};` ? (unchecked)

Comment: @Alex No, but `std::array<int,5> arr{1,2,3,4,5};` would be legal.

Comment: @Alex the `=` is allowed. @Zeta Two braces are "required" because the array itself is a struct (one pair of braces) with an internal C array (second pair of braces). You are allowed by the standard to omit the second pair in this circumstance.

Comment: @Malloc: Assuming CWG1270 is fixed. Otherwise it's still `std::array<int,5> arr{{1,2,3,4,5}};`

Comment: @Wooble - not necessarily. For invalid code, the language definition requires "a diagnostic"; once the compiler issues a diagnostic, it's free to continue to compile the code, giving it an implementation-specific meaning. That's the hook for implementation-specific extensions.

Comment: @Simple: Doh. Totally forgot about that. See, that's what I was talking about when I said _"missing something important" (or trivial)_ :D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192185/using-stdarray-with-initialization-lists).

> std::array is funny. It is defined basically like this:
>
> template struct std::array {   T a[size]; };
>
> It is a struct which contains an array. It does not have a constructor
>   that takes an initializer list. But std::array is an aggregate by the
>   rules of C++11, and therefore it can be created by aggregate
>   initialization. To aggregate initialize the array inside the struct,
>   you need a second set of curly braces:
>
> std::array strings = {{ "a", "b" }};
>
> Note that the standard does suggest that the extra braces can be
>   elided in this case. So it likely is a GCC bug.

I believe it might be related to [this defect](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3367.html#1270), which has been linked in several questions.

Here's an [answer regarding it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400125/1508519):

> However, these extra braces may only be elided "in a declaration of
>   the form T x = { a };" (C++11 §8.5.1/11), that is, when the old style
>   = is used . This rule allowing brace elision does not apply for direct list initialization. A footnote here reads: "Braces cannot be elided
>   in other uses of list-initialization."
>
> There is a defect report concerning this restriction: CWG defect
>   #1270. If the proposed resolution is adopted, brace elision will be allowed for other forms of list initialization, ...

I noticed that the error does not appear in gcc 4.8.1, but it does on a very old version  (4.4.7), and I think this is the patch (because the <strike>defect</strike> proposed solution is dated Feb 2012, and this link is dated Mar 2012):

http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2012-03/msg00215.html

Comment: Note that the example given is of the `T x = { a };` form. So only the last quote applies. CWG 1270 covers other cases, e.g. the one in Alex'comment on the question.

Comment: @remyabel: The "helpful comment" you quoted implies that there's conceptual difference between aggregate class initialization and built-in array initialization. It seems to imply that aggregate class is handled by "classic" aggregate initialization, while array initialization is a new "initializer list" initialization. Does this distinction really exist in C++11? In C++03 and before arrays were aggregates, meaning that everything was handled uniformly by aggregate initialization.

Answer (score 3):

It is an annoying "safety" warning that was introduced in one of the earlier versions of GCC for both C and C++ aggregate initializers. If I remember correctly, it predates C++11 and is not really related to C++11 (again, it affects C as much as it affects C++). Basically, it requires an additional level of nested `{}` when beginning an initializer for each nested aggregate. The language does not require this, which is why it is just a warning.

The warning in question could be useful in many cases, but the implementation was poorly thought through. One completely preposterous consequence of that warning is that it "kills" the `= { 0 }` initializer idiom in C language. (In C anything can be initialized with `= { 0 }`, but because of this annoying warning one is forced to selectively use things like `= {{0}}`, `= {{{0}}}` and such).

In C++ `std::array` class is an aggregate, for which `= { ... }` initializers are handled by the good-old built-in aggregate initialization, not by a dedicated constructor. (In C++11 the rules of aggregate initialization were rewritten in terms of *initializer lists*, but the general C-style behavior was intentionally preserved through the possibility of *brace elision*.) For this reason `std::array` initialization is also affected by that warning. `std::array` is an aggregate containing the actual array, which is also an aggregate. For this reason, in order to get to the array elements in the initializer GCC encourages you to open *two* levels of `{}`.

So, with `std::array` you just found another example of when that warning does more harm than good.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's really no way in which a reasonable compiler can screw this up, for a class this simple.

Comment: I would expect a reasonable compiler to complain about non-conforming code and this happens here. I see your point, but allowing this feels really wrong somehow.